# How do you identify natural and forced neighbors in Jump Point Search?

Tags: search, point, path-finding, a-star

I am trying to implement Jump Point Search, an optimization on A* that reduces the number of nodes in the open list by na average of 20x,  as well as memory consumption. The algorithm was implemented according to the original research paper and some online tutorials, but the program enters an infinite recursion loop when searching for natural and forced neighbors, which causes a stack overflow. Pathfinding A* is already working and I am just adding the JPS functions to it.

Here is the code for those functions:

```
void Movement::GetNaturalNeighbors(std::vector<Node>& output, Node& currentNode)
{
    int nextX = currentNode.pos.x + currentNode.direction.x;
    int nextY = currentNode.pos.y + currentNode.direction.y;

    // Straight line pruning excludes all neighbors except the one directly in front of currentNode
    if(!g_terrain.IsWall(nextX, nextY))
    {       
        Map[nextX][nextY].parent = &Map[currentNode.pos.x][currentNode.pos.y];
        Map[nextX][nextY].direction.x = Map[nextX][nextY].parent->direction.x;
        Map[nextX][nextY].direction.y = Map[nextX][nextY].parent->direction.y;
        Map[nextX][nextY].heurCost = GetHeuristicCost(nextX, nextY);
        // Movement cost for diagonals is square root of 2
        Map[nextX][nextY].movCost = currentNode.movCost + 1.0f;
        Map[nextX][nextY].pos.x = nextX;
        Map[nextX][nextY].pos.y = nextY;
        if ((Map[nextX][nextY].movCost + Map[nextX][nextY].heurCost) < (currentNode.movCost + currentNode.heurCost))
        {
            output.push_back(Map[nextX][nextY]);
        }
    }

    int dirX = currentNode.direction.x;
    int dirY = currentNode.direction.y;

    // If we are moving diagonally, add the adjacent nodes in the same direction
    if(dirX!= 0 && dirY!=0)
    {
        if((dirY == +1) &&(!g_terrain.IsWall(currentNode.pos.x+ neighborX[TOP], currentNode.pos.y+ neighborY[TOP])))
        {
            int naturalNeighborX = currentNode.pos.x+ neighborX[TOP];
            int naturalNeighborY = currentNode.pos.y+ neighborY[TOP];
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].direction.x = neighborX[TOP];
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].direction.y = neighborY[TOP];
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].parent = &Map[currentNode.pos.x][currentNode.pos.y];
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].heurCost = GetHeuristicCost(nextX, nextY);
            // Movement cost for diagonals is square root of 2
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].movCost = currentNode.movCost + 1.41421f;
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].pos.x = naturalNeighborX;
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].pos.y = naturalNeighborY;
            if ((Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].movCost + Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].heurCost) < (currentNode.movCost + currentNode.heurCost))
            {
                output.push_back(Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY]);
            }
        }
        else if(!g_terrain.IsWall(currentNode.pos.x+ neighborX[BOTTOM], currentNode.pos.y+ neighborY[BOTTOM]))
        {
            int naturalNeighborX = currentNode.pos.x+ neighborX[BOTTOM];
            int naturalNeighborY = currentNode.pos.y+ neighborY[BOTTOM];
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].direction.x = neighborX[BOTTOM];
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].direction.y = neighborY[BOTTOM];
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].parent = &Map[currentNode.pos.x][currentNode.pos.y];
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].heurCost = GetHeuristicCost(nextX, nextY);
            // Movement cost for diagonals is square root of 2m
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].movCost = currentNode.movCost + 1.41421f;
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].pos.x = nextX;
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].pos.y = nextY;
            if ((Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].movCost + Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].heurCost) < (currentNode.movCost + currentNode.heurCost))
            {
                output.push_back(Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY]);
            }
        }

        if((dirX == +1) && (!g_terrain.IsWall(currentNode.pos.x+ neighborX[RIGHT], currentNode.pos.y+ neighborY[RIGHT])))
        {
            int naturalNeighborX = currentNode.pos.x+ neighborX[RIGHT];
            int naturalNeighborY = currentNode.pos.y+ neighborY[RIGHT];
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].direction.x = neighborX[RIGHT];
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].direction.y = neighborY[RIGHT];
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].parent = &Map[currentNode.pos.x][currentNode.pos.y];
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].heurCost = GetHeuristicCost(nextX, nextY);
            // Movement cost for diagonals is square root of 2
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].movCost = currentNode.movCost + 1.41421f;
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].pos.x = naturalNeighborX;
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].pos.y = naturalNeighborY;
            if ((Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].movCost + Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].heurCost) < (currentNode.movCost + currentNode.heurCost))
            {
                output.push_back(Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY]);  
            }
        }
        else if(!g_terrain.IsWall(currentNode.pos.x+ neighborX[LEFT], currentNode.pos.y+ neighborY[LEFT]))
        {
            int naturalNeighborX = currentNode.pos.x+ neighborX[LEFT];
            int naturalNeighborY = currentNode.pos.y+ neighborY[LEFT];
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborX].direction.x = neighborX[LEFT];
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborX].direction.y = neighborX[LEFT];
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborX].parent = &Map[currentNode.pos.x][currentNode.pos.y];
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborX].heurCost = GetHeuristicCost(nextX, nextY);
            // Movement cost for diagonals is square root of 2
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].movCost = currentNode.movCost + 1.41421f;
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].pos.x = nextX;
            Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].pos.y = nextY;
            if ((Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].movCost + Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY].heurCost) < (currentNode.movCost + currentNode.heurCost))
            {
                output.push_back(Map[naturalNeighborX][naturalNeighborY]);
            }
        }
    }

}


void Movement::GetForcedNeighbors(std::vector<Node>& output, Node& currentNode)
{
    int dir_x = currentNode.direction.x;
    int dir_y = currentNode.direction.y;

    int nextNodeX = currentNode.pos.x + dir_x;
    int nextNodeY = currentNode.pos.y + dir_y;


    // Forced neighbors only exist for diagonal moves
    if((dir_x != 0) && (dir_y != 0))
    {
        // Check for diagonal forced neighbors

        if(dir_x == +1)
        {
            // Does the top right diagonal have any forced neighbors ?
            if(g_terrain.IsWall(nextNodeX + neighborX[TOP_RIGHT], nextNodeY + neighborY[TOP_RIGHT]) && !g_terrain.IsWall(nextNodeX + neighborX[TOP], nextNodeY + neighborY[TOP]))
            {   
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].direction.x = neighborX[TOP];
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].direction.y = neighborY[TOP];
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].parent = &Map[currentNode.pos.x][currentNode.pos.y];
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].heurCost = GetHeuristicCost(nextNodeX, nextNodeY);
                // Movement cost for diagonals is square root of 2
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].movCost = currentNode.movCost + 1.41421f;
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].pos.x = nextNodeX;
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].pos.y = nextNodeY;

                if ((Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].movCost + Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].heurCost) < (currentNode.movCost + currentNode.heurCost))
                {
                    output.push_back(Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY]);
                }
            }

            // Does the bottom right diagonal have any forced neighbors ?
            if(g_terrain.IsWall(nextNodeX + neighborX[BOTTOM_RIGHT], nextNodeY + neighborY[BOTTOM_RIGHT]) && !g_terrain.IsWall(nextNodeX + neighborX[BOTTOM], nextNodeY + neighborY[BOTTOM]))
            {   
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].direction.x = neighborX[BOTTOM];
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].direction.y = neighborY[BOTTOM];
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].parent = &Map[currentNode.pos.x][currentNode.pos.y];
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].heurCost = GetHeuristicCost(nextNodeX, nextNodeY);
                // Movement cost for diagonals is square root of 2
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].movCost =  currentNode.movCost + 1.41421f;
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].pos.x = nextNodeX;
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].pos.y = nextNodeY;

                output.push_back(Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY]);
            }

        }

        if(dir_x == -1)
        {
            // Does the top left diagonal have any forced neighbors ?
            if(g_terrain.IsWall(nextNodeX + neighborX[TOP_LEFT], nextNodeY + neighborY[TOP_LEFT]) && !g_terrain.IsWall(nextNodeX + neighborX[TOP], nextNodeY + neighborY[TOP]))
            {
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].direction.x = neighborX[TOP];
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].direction.y = neighborY[TOP];
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].parent = &Map[currentNode.pos.x][currentNode.pos.y];
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].heurCost = GetHeuristicCost(nextNodeX, nextNodeY);
                // Movement cost for diagonals is square root of 2
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].movCost = ((dir_x == 0) || (dir_y == 0))? currentNode.movCost + 1.0f: currentNode.movCost + 1.41421f;
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].pos.x = nextNodeX;
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].pos.y = nextNodeY;

                output.push_back(Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY]);
            }

            // Does the bottom left diagonal have any forced neighbors ?
            if(g_terrain.IsWall(nextNodeX + neighborX[BOTTOM_LEFT], nextNodeY + neighborY[BOTTOM_LEFT]) && !g_terrain.IsWall(nextNodeX + neighborX[BOTTOM], nextNodeY + neighborY[BOTTOM]))
            {
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].direction.x = neighborX[BOTTOM];
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].direction.y = neighborY[BOTTOM];
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].parent = &Map[currentNode.pos.x][currentNode.pos.y];
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].heurCost = GetHeuristicCost(nextNodeX, nextNodeY);
                // Movement cost for diagonals is square root of 2
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].movCost = ((dir_x == 0) || (dir_y == 0))? currentNode.movCost + 1.0f: currentNode.movCost + 1.41421f;
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].pos.x = nextNodeX;
                Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY].pos.y = nextNodeY;

                output.push_back(Map[nextNodeX][nextNodeY]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything else follows the logic of the original document, but these two functions are the only two I am unsure about. Both the creators and many tutorials do not explain in depth how to identify them.

My implementation of A* stores the world information in a 2D matrix called Map instead of employing a closed list. The open list is merely a vector of what nodes to open. Nodes contain their x and y positions, heuristic cost and movement cost (more commonly known as given cost) and the direction the player was facing in when he stepped on the tile. The player only moves in x and y.

I apologize for the wall of text, but this is my first post and I wanted to post as much relevant information as possible.

Comment: Anyone ? I knew this algorithm was fairly recent and , because of that, not so well known, but isn't there anyone who already implemented it ?

Comment: I have looked at Jump Point Search, but decided it was inappropriate for the type of path finding I need for my game. I implemented Bidirectional A* instead. Then I took one look at your (**Copy-Paste** code, and decided that I didn't need that aggravation either. Haven't you heard of DNY: Don't Repeat Yourself? If you improve your code you will win (at least) two ways - more people will be interested in looking at it, and you probably have a 50% chance of finding your bug.

Comment: Already solved the bug. Basically, I could simplify this to a few lines of code by using enums and some operations with modulo. One thing I didn't understand though, Peter, Bidirectional Pathfinding starts one search at the beginning and one at the end and alternates between them. When they coincide, the final path is built. But it might take longer for the paths to overlap, normally longer than normal pathfinding and consuming more resources. Maybe your map representation is most suited for this approach. In that case, could you go into details ? (Not trying to be sarcastic, just curious).

Comment: Actually, for the long diagonals on my map the number of hexagons in the closed set is about 89,000 for bidirectional, and about 240,000 for unidirectional A*. The reason is that the **cone** of alternatives tightens as the two sides converge. Or another way to look at it: The cone of alternatives is proportional to the square of the path length; In bidirectional each half explores about 1/4 as many hexagons, for 2 * 1/4 = 1/2 as many as unidirectional.

Comment: The greater reduction noted above is due to an asymmetry in my map, where one direction took 50% longer than the other. The net for bidirectional is 1/2 the favoured direction, and 1/3 the unflavoured direction.

Comment: Oh, I see. That makes sense. You never know which side will yield an answer faster, so you try both. One suggestion though, instead of having an open and closed list, use a boolean to tell you if the node is on the open and one to tell if it is on the closed list, then express your map as a graph. Then pre-compute the neighbors when the map is loaded. Eliminating the closed list normally speeds up the search speed by 10x.

Comment: I have already pre-computed all step-costs. Closed- and open-set elimination can only buy me 6.7%; I suggest you investigate a better hash-function if you are getting 90% time reduction; I use `x<<16 | y` where x and y are the (short) integer coordinates of each hex.